# Unique Factorization in Number Ring

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

I am having a difficulty understanding ideals in a number ring; if I have (2), does it mean that it is a ring generated by $2$ (e.g. {$2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$}).
If so, why is $(2)=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$? It seems like the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ generated by $4$, $2+2\sqrt{-5}$, and $(1+\sqrt{-5})^2=-4+2\sqrt{-5}$, but we $(2)$ does not contain $2+2\sqrt{-5}$. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something....

Answer (score 2):

The notation $(2)$ means the *ideal* generated by $2$, not just the subring generated by $2$.  That is, it is the smallest ideal in your ring that contains $2$.  So it contains $2r$ for *every* element $r$ of your ring, since an ideal must be closed under multiplication by arbitrary ring elements.  In particular, if you take $r=1+\sqrt{-5}$, you see that $2+2\sqrt{-5}$ is in $(2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question; does it mean that $(a,b)=${$ar+bs| r,s \in R$}?

Comment: @H.Gro Yes: that's (almost) the definition of $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given two ideals $A=(a_1,\ldots)$ and $B=(b_1,\ldots)$, $A=B$ if and only if each $a_i$ is in $B$ and each $b_i$ is in $A$.

Here:
$A=(2)$ and
$B=\left(2,1+\sqrt{-5}\right)^2=\left(2,1+\sqrt{-5}\right)\left(2,1+\sqrt{-5}\right)=\left(4, 2+2\sqrt{-5}, -4+2\sqrt{-5}\right)$.

We have:
$4=2\cdot2\in A$,
$2+2\sqrt{-5}=\left[1+\sqrt{-5}\right]\cdot2\in A$, and
$-4+2\sqrt{-5}=\left[-2+\sqrt{-5}\right]\cdot2\in A$.

Likewise: $2=(-1)\cdot4+1\cdot\left[2+2\sqrt{-5}\right]+(-1)\cdot\left(-4+2\sqrt{-5}\right)\in B$.