# Show $2 = (2, 1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Show $2 = (2, 1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Apologies if this may seem a trivial question, however, I am some difficulty showing this.

My Attempt:

$(2, 1+\sqrt{-5}) * (2, 1+\sqrt{-5}) = (4 + 1 + 2\sqrt{-5} - 5) = (2\sqrt{-5})$.

I am not sure how to proceed to show that $(2\sqrt{-5}) = (2)$

Comment: And also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1991259/11619). Tsk. Tsk.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Alas, none of the answers there efficiently cover *all* the points where the OP is having difficulty (see the comments on TS's answer) That's why I answered. There are very likely threads that cover it all (efficiently), but I couldn't quickly find any. No need to be snarky ("tsk tsk")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiplying ideals, you have to multiply each generator together to get generators of the new ideal.

So you actually have $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})\cdot(2,1+\sqrt{-5}) = (4, 2+2\sqrt{-5}, 2+2\sqrt{-5}, -4+2\sqrt{-5})$.

If you look at the four generators (three unique generators) of the new ideal, you should quickly see they have a gcd of $2$.

Comment: I can see that they have a gcd of $2$, however, wouldn't that just show that $(2)$ is in $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ and not equality?

Comment: The ideal $(2)$ is by definition all multiples of $2$ in the ring. So if all the generators of an ideal are multiples of $2$, you have that the ideal is contained in $(2)$. To show that inclusion goes the other way, show that $2$ can be expressed as a linear combination of your generators.

Comment: @mlimber The other direction is easy if you use modular reduction as in the Euclidean algorithm, e.g. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$2=2\cdot 2^2-2(1+\sqrt{-5}) + (1+\sqrt{-5})^2, $$ so $(2) \supset (2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$.  The other way is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Note $\,(a,b)^2 = (a^2,ab,b^2)\,$ so with $\,w=\sqrt{-5},\,$ using $\,(2,I) = (2,\, I\bmod 2)\,$ yields

$\ \ (2,1\!+\!w)^2 = 2(2,\underbrace{1\!+\!w,-2\!+\!w}_{\large I}) = (2)\ $ by $\bmod 2\!:\ I = (1\!+\!w,w) = (1,w) = (1)$

Comment: The first equality follows by basic ideal arithmetic laws (distributive, commutative, associative)

$$ (a,b)(a,b) = ((a,b)a,(a,b)b) = ((aa,ba),(ab,bb)) = (aa,ba,ab,bb) = (aa,ab,bb)\qquad\qquad\qquad $$